Migrating router path from expressjs4 to 5
Im migrating an older Express.js v4 service to v5.
I encountered an error while migrating this code
router.get('/*', (req, res) => { ... });

The problem is with the /* wildcard. What is the proper way achieving this with Express.js v5 router?
edit:
The migration docs say:

The wildcard * must have a name, matching the behavior of parameters
:, use /splat instead of /

Im wondering if thats the only way? any other try ended with errors.

Editing original answer:
After digging more into this problem, I don't find an easy way to handle this with router.
As a workaround you can have a fallback route in the main express app like this:
var app = express();

// Some routes defined

app.get((req, res) => {
  // handle the request
});

This will capture all routes not captured already in previous routes.
Hopefully this works for your solution.

that throws an error. the migration docs say "The wildcard * must have a name, matching the behavior of parameters :, use /splat instead of /" but im wondering if thats the only way?

You're right, adding an alternative solution to the problem
